# How to change state in recoil selector

Tags: reactjs, typescript, recoiljs

I'm trying to change state in my selector similar to normal state change but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Can someone help me?

It's my atom:

```
export interface iBook {
  id: number;
  title: string;
}

const initState: iBook[] = [{ id: 1, title: "a" }];

export const bookState = atom({
  key: "bookState",
  default: initState,
});
```

And now selector which didn't work

```
export const onChange = selector({
  key: "onChange",
  get: ({ get }) => get(bookState),
  set: ({ set, get }, id) => {
    const books= get(bookState);
    set(
      bookState,
      books.map((book) => {
        if (book.id === id)
          return {
            ...book,
            title: "b",
          };
      })
    );
  },
});
```

It shows error on "bookState"

> Argument of type 'RecoilState<iBook[]>' is not assignable to
> parameter of type 'RecoilState<({ value: number; title: string; } |
> undefined)[]>'.   Types of property '__cTag' are incompatible.
> Type '(t: iBook[]) => void' is not assignable to type '(t: ({ title: string; id: number; } | undefined)[]) => void'.
> Types of parameters 't' and 't' are incompatible.
> Type '({ title: string; id: number; } | undefined)[]' is not assignable to type 'iBook[]'.  TS2345

And this is hook which work in component but I want it in selector:

```
   setBooks(
      books.map((book) => {
        if (book.id === id)
          return {
            ...book,
            title: "b",
          };
        return book;
      })
    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not returning the book object if the id doesn't match, so you return undefined. Return the book object:

```js
export const onChange = selector({
  key: "onChange",
  get: ({ get }) => get(bookState),
  set: ({ set, get }, id) => {
    const books= get(bookState);
    set(
      bookState,
      books.map((book) => {
        if (book.id === id) {
          return {
            ...book,
            title: "b",
          };
        }
        return book;
      })
    );
  },
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it helps ‍ Do you know if it's a good practice? I mean passing id of object which should be changed. I'm asking because I can't assign type to this argument in a selector, for examle ({set, get}, id: number).

Comment: It is not good practice. Your selector doesn't really make any sense to me. I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. But a selector should almost always just derive state, that is why it's called a selector.

Comment: So how can I optimize code when in different components I'm using same code for changing atoms?

Comment: Just write a custom hook with a callback that gets called.